# Connect to wifi programmatically in Xamarin Forms Android 10

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am unable to connect to wifi in Android 10. The code I have works fine till Android 9, I have been trying to implement the same for Android 10 without any luck :(

```
        private void RequestNetwork(string _ssid, string _passphrase)
        {
            var specifier = new WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder()
                .SetSsid(_ssid)
                .SetWpa2Passphrase(_passphrase)
                .Build();

            var request = new NetworkRequest.Builder()
                .AddTransportType(TransportType.Wifi) // we want WiFi
                .RemoveCapability(NetCapability.Internet) // Internet not required
                .SetNetworkSpecifier(specifier) // we want _our_ network
                .Build();

            NetworkCallback _callback = new NetworkCallback();
            connection_manager.RequestNetwork(request, _callback);
        }

        private class NetworkCallback : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback
        {
            public Action NetworkAvailable { get; set; }
            //bool IsBusy = false;
            public override void OnAvailable(Network network)
            {
                base.OnAvailable(network);
                connection_manager.BindProcessToNetwork(network);
            }

            public override void OnUnavailable()
            {
                base.OnUnavailable();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

I see that you copied code from [my blog post](https://blog.ostebaronen.dk/2019/11/android-10-wifi.html) based on the comments. I guess you have tried running the sample App I provided on GitHub?

Anyways, first of all make sure you have added the following permissions in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Except for the missing permissions the code you provided should work and show you a system dialog looking like this:

[image: Android "Connect to device" system dialog]

Comment: Yes, thank you for your prompt response. The code is from your blog post indeed. I also left a message there, I just saw that you replied there as well. The permissions seem to be okay as I get a toast saying the connection is successful

Comment: Hi, turns out it has something to do with my OnePlus 7T. I tried it on a Samsung S10 and it works fine. Thank you for your help and the article.

Comment: That is strange. I have a OnePlus 6 and it works fine there, shouldn't be much different. Can you maybe try go into WiFi settings and check stuff like Smart WiFi and stuff like that is disabled and try again

Comment: Just checked. Turned off "Intelligently select wifi", same behavior. 

Did some more testing, if my phone is not already connected to another wifi, it seems to work. Strange indeed

Comment: @Singhal2,It seems that you have one solution, if yes, please remember to mark helpful post as answer, thanks.

Comment: Well, I checked the same on OnePlus 7T and Samsung S10 and it is not working correctly. I have not yet found a complete solution.

Comment: @Singhal2, It seems that it doesn't work all device,but if you have one complete solution, please share it here, thanks.

Comment: Hi, I could not find a solution using the RequestNetwork method (as recommended by Google for Android 10), however, if you use the same old AddNetwork and EnableNetwork methods, they seem to be working fine even on android 10 when targetSDKVersion is set to 9. I understand that this is not ideal as apps after August 2020 would require the target version to be 10. I will soon file a bug with Android to get more information.

Comment: @Singhal2 If you have any feedback,please share here, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the my code for connecting wifi but problem is after connecting wifi internet not worked.

**If your internet problem is not occured then please share your code with us:**

```
try
                {
                    var connectivityManager = Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.ConnectivityService) as ConnectivityManager;
                    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.WifiService);
                    if (!wifiManager.IsWifiEnabled)
                    {
                        Forms.Context.StartActivity(new Intent(Android.Provider.Settings.ActionWifiSettings));
                        return false;
                    }

                    var callback = new NetworkCallback(connectivityManager)
                    {
                        NetworkAvailable = network =>
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Connected");
                            MessagingCenter.Send<string, Boolean>("ConnectModel", "connecttowifi", true);
                        },
                        NetworkUnavailable = () =>
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Not Connected");
                            MessagingCenter.Send<string, Boolean>("ConnectModel", "connecttowifi", false);
                        }
                    };
                    var specifier = new WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder()
                    .SetSsid(ssid)
                    .SetWpa2Passphrase(password)
                    .Build();
                    var request = new NetworkRequest.Builder()
                        .AddTransportType(TransportType.Wifi)
                        //.AddCapability(NetCapability.Internet)
                        //.RemoveCapability(NetCapability.Internet)
                        .SetNetworkSpecifier(specifier)
                        .Build();
                    connectivityManager.RequestNetwork(request, callback);

                    return true;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.Write(e.Message);
                    return false;
                }
```